# Function only returning return value it is not supposed to reach

Tags: c, return

I am working on a project for a programming class, where the goal is to verify a strength of a password based on different security levels. My problem is that with 2nd level, the:

Counter of numbers and special characters isn't working properly and isn't detecting numbers (it was working before I put it in its own function), but more importantly, the function only returns the value set in the very end. I have no idea what else to try.

```
int level2() {
    while ((fgets(given_string, 100, stdin) != NULL)) {
        for (int i = 0; given_string[i] != '\n'; i++) {
            if (given_string[i] >= 'a' && given_string[i] <= 'z') {
                lowerCaseLetterFound++;
            } else if (given_string[i] >= 'A' && given_string[i] <= 'Z') {
                upperCaseLetterFound++;
            } else if (given_string[i] >= '0' && given_string[i] <= '9') {
                numberFound++;
            } else {
                specialCharacterFound++;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("%d %d %d %d\n", lowerCaseLetterFound, upperCaseLetterFound, numberFound, specialCharacterFound);

    if (param == 1 || param == 2) {
        if (lowerCaseLetterFound >= 1 && upperCaseLetterFound >= 1) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    } else if (param == 3) {
        if (((lowerCaseLetterFound >= 1 && upperCaseLetterFound >= 1) && numberFound >= 1) ||
            ((lowerCaseLetterFound >= 1 && upperCaseLetterFound >= 1) && specialCharacterFound >= 1)) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    } else if (param >= 4) {
        if (lowerCaseLetterFound >= 1 && upperCaseLetterFound >= 1 && numberFound >= 1 &&
            specialCharacterFound >= 1) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

PS: This is my first time asking question here, and I am a programming newbie. Thanks for your help.

Update: Adding the whole code as I have it RN.

```
char given_string[100];
int lowerCaseLetterFound = 0;
int upperCaseLetterFound = 0;
int numberFound = 0;
int specialCharacterFound = 0;
int repeatedCharacter = 0;
int param;
int level;

int level1 () {
    while ((fgets(given_string, 100, stdin) != NULL)) {
        for (int i = 0; given_string[i] != '\n'; i++) {
            if (given_string[i] >= 'a' && given_string[i] <= 'z') {
                lowerCaseLetterFound++;
            } else if (given_string[i] >= 'A' && given_string[i] <= 'Z') {
                upperCaseLetterFound++;
        }
    }
}
        if (lowerCaseLetterFound >= 1 && upperCaseLetterFound >= 1) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return 0;
    }
}

int level2() {
    while ((fgets(given_string, 100, stdin) != NULL)) {
        for (int i = 0; given_string[i] != '\n'; i++) {
            if (given_string[i] >= 'a' && given_string[i] <= 'z') {
                lowerCaseLetterFound++;
            } else if (given_string[i] >= 'A' && given_string[i] <= 'Z') {
                upperCaseLetterFound++;
            } else if (given_string[i] >= '0' && given_string[i] <= '9') {
                numberFound++;
            } else {
                specialCharacterFound++;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("%d %d %d %d\n", lowerCaseLetterFound, upperCaseLetterFound, numberFound, specialCharacterFound);

    if (param == 1 || param == 2) {
        if (lowerCaseLetterFound >= 1 && upperCaseLetterFound >= 1) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    } else if (param == 3) {
        if (((lowerCaseLetterFound >= 1 && upperCaseLetterFound >= 1) && numberFound >= 1) ||
            ((lowerCaseLetterFound >= 1 && upperCaseLetterFound >= 1) && specialCharacterFound >= 1)) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    } else if (param >= 4) {
        if (lowerCaseLetterFound >= 1 && upperCaseLetterFound >= 1 && numberFound >= 1 &&
            specialCharacterFound >= 1) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

/*
int level3() {
    while ((fgets(given_string, 100, stdin) != NULL)) {
        for (int i = 0; given_string[i] != '\n'; i++) {
            if (given_string[i] >= 'a' && given_string[i] <= 'z') {
                lowerCaseLetterFound++;
            } else if (given_string[i] >= 'A' && given_string[i] <= 'Z') {
                upperCaseLetterFound++;
            } else if (given_string[i] >= '0' && given_string[i] <= '9') {
                numberFound++;
            } else {
                specialCharacterFound++;
            }
        }
    }
}
 */

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    //ukládám argumenty, prozatím pouze 2 ze 3
    if (argc <= 1) {
        printf("Not enough arguments provided. Please, provide LEVEL and PARAM arugments.\n");
    } else if (argc >= 5) {
        printf("Too many arguments provided.\n");
    }
    int level = atoi(argv[1]);
    int param = atoi(argv[2]);

    if (level <= 0 || level >= 5) {
        printf("Level must be 1 through 4.\n");
    }

    if (param <= 0) {
        printf("Parameter is not a full positive number.\n");
    }

    //vyhodnocování na základě zadaných parametrů - kontrola
    //LEVEL = 1

    if (level == 1) {
        level1();
        if (level1() == 1) {
            printf("Password passed check 1.\n");
    } else {
            printf("Password did not pass check 1.\n");
        }
    }

    if (level == 2) {
        if (level1() == 1) {
            if (level2() == 1) {
                printf("Password did pass the check.\n");
            }
        } else {
            printf("Password did not pass the check.\n");
        }

        if (level1() == 0) {
            printf("Password did not pass the check.\n");
        }
    }

    if (level == 3) {

    }
}
```

Comment: definitions of `xxxFound` are missing

Comment: Looks like they are global variables.

Comment: if the line read by `fgets`  is longer than 100 character then newline **will not** be put to the buffer. This will overflow buffer in the loop scanning `given_string` because there is no newline there.

Comment: @SouravGhosh, I'm interested in their types. They may not be `int`s.

Comment: Perhaps `param` is zero or negative... we can't tell from the posted code. Please edit the question and provide the information

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. Read this: [ask]

Comment: Unrelated: Stop using global variables. Define the variables inside the function.

Comment: Unrelated: Change `for (int i = 0; given_string[i] != '\n'; i++) {` to `for (int i = 0; given_string[i] != '\n' && given_string[i] != '\0'; i++) {`

Comment: Unrelated: Perhaps read about these helpful functions https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man0/ctype.h.0p.html

Comment: You're calling the `level1` function multiple times.

Comment: `while ((fgets(...) != NULL)) { ... }` Will consume *all* the input stream untill an error is encountered or end-of-file is reached without reading any character. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Try to put your code in more than one function.

I think you can't print sth in your function. You should return just one thing you want to get from your function and then in another function, get input the first function's return.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is that you’re re-defining your global variables in your main function. For example, when you do `int param = atoi(argv[2]);` in your main, `param` is scoped to your main. As soon as you leave your main function, you will be accessing the global `param` which has never been set.

You can either remove the variable type in your main so you are setting the global variables:

```
param = atoi(argv[2]);
```

Or get rid of the global variables and pass the ones created in main to any function that needs them.